# Google login in Reactnative App with Strapi

Tags: react-native, strapi, react-google-login

I want to implement google login in react native app using strapi. Is there any proper documentation or steps to follow? I didn't understand how to do with strapi. I have found an example with react js.

Comment: try this
https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/4491

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it:
First of all, install google-signin package and do the necessary setup changes:
[@react-native-google-signin/google-signin](https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin)

Once you are sure that you have finished the configuration, you can perform login like below:

```
 try {
      await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
      await GoogleSignin.signIn();
      const { accessToken } = await GoogleSignin.getTokens();
      const resp = await axios.get(`/auth/google/callback?access_token=${accessToken}`);
      if (resp.status !== 200) {
        //Handle fail case
        return;
      }

      const data = resp.data
      // Handle the data and do your stuff like navigate to the home screen.
    } catch (error: any) {
      if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
        // user cancelled the login flow
      } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
        // operation (e.g. sign in) is in progress already
      } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
        // play services not available or outdated
      } else {
        // some other error happened
      }
    }
```

Comment: It works for me, thanks! Additionally, I want to save firstName and lastName to custom fields from google account like email. How can I do it? Couldn't find a solution.